# Make an unordered list that looks like a select box

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to make an unordered list appear as a select box, and if at all possible, without Javascript. I don't know where to take this from here.

```css
select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.2em 0.4em;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #acacac;
  background: #fff;
}
select {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}
select:disabled {
  z-index: 1;
}
.select-wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.select-wrap:after {
  content: '\f078'; /* fa-chevron-down */
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  right: 0.5em;
  top: 0.2em;
}
option {
  padding-left: 0.5em;
}

/* Now for the list */

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul.select {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.2em 0.4em;
  width: 100%;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #acacac;
  background: #fff;
}
ul.select li a {
  display: block;
  color: inherit;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css?ver=1.0' type='text/css' media='all' />

<div class="select-wrap">
  <select id="Select1">
    <option value="First">First</option>
    <option value="Second">Second</option>
    <option value="Third">Third</option>
  </select>
</div>
<!-- /.select-wrap-->

<br />
<br />

<div class="select-wrap">
  <ul class="select">
    <li><a href="#" title="First">First</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" title="Second">Second</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" title="Third">Third</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible without javascript, but why not just use a select box?

Comment: @BramH Because I am making a list of hyperlinks.

Comment: What's going to happen when you click on a link - are you just going to navigate away or you wanting it to be selected like the dropdown would be

Comment: @Pete To navigate away, as a normal hyperlink.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get pretty close with `<input type="checkbox">` with `:checked` to handle the dropdown. And use `<label>` for styling. But it won't do the `default` selected item like in `<select>`.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.select-checkbox {
  display: none;
}
.select-label {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 4px;
}
.select-label:before {
  content: "\25BE";
  float: right;
}
.select-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background: #eee;
  display: none;
}
.select-checkbox:checked ~ .select-wrap {
  display: block;
}
.select {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
}
.select a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="checkbox" class="select-checkbox" id="c1">
  <label for="c1" class="select-label">Click to open dropdown</label>
  <div class="select-wrap">
    <ul class="select">
      <li><a href="#" title="First">First</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="Second">Second</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="Third">Third</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you are trying to accomplish?

```css
ul {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 4px 17px 0;
  list-style: none;
}
ul li {
  font: bold 12px/18px sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  background: #2980b9;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  color: #fff;
}
ul li:hover {
  background: #555;
  color: #fff;
}
ul li ul {
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
ul li ul li {
  min-width: 80px;
  background-color: #555;
}
ul li ul li > a { 
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block; 
  color: #fff;
}
ul li ul li:hover {
    background: #666;
}
ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
ul li > span {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0 0 -3px 5px;
 width: 12px;
 height: 12px;
 background-image: url('https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ios-7-icons/50/down4-24.png');
 background-size: 12px 12px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    First<span class="arrow-down"></span>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Second</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Third</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="select-wrap">
```

Answer (score 1):

The closest i could get without js

```css
.select{
  height:20px;
  width:200px;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-color:#FFFFFF;
  border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.select:hover{
  height:auto;
}

.select li{
  height:20px;
  line-height:20px;
  padding-left:5px;
}

.select li:hover{
  background-color:#EEEEFF;
}

.select li a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#000000;
  font-family:calibri;
}

.select li:first-child a:after{
  content:' ';
  background-image: url('https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ios-7-icons/50/down4-24.png');
  background-size:16px 16px;
  background-position:center center;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  float:right;
  height:20px;
  width:20px;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:20px;
}
```

```html
    <ul class="select">
      <li><a href="#" title="First">First</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="Second">Second</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="Third">Third</a></li>
    </ul>
```